# How to maintain online statistics for big data?

Tags: sql, postgresql, architecture, bigdata, olap

I have a DB with *relativly* (for our capacity) large rows ~ 45000000. I have ~ 500-1000 users who need online statistic from this DB by different criteria (client, priority, etc).

In general, approximately 2500000 rows are affected for this SQL aggregation. I use 1 minute TTL cache.

But it takes too much time anyway to generate such statistics.

So, I need to speed this up. I added some indexes, but it's not a silver bullet. I think I need to totally refactor my statistic system.
The thing is, I'm not sure how exactly I should do that.

Maybe I should create different db\table for stats, but I have new event every second, so data will be recalculating every second, which is totally absurd.

Or maybe I should store all posible calculated data and changes (increase\decrease) it by events of delete\insert. I think it's some kind of OLAP system.

So my question is how to maintain accurate aggregated statistics with different criteria with large number of rows?

Comment: Assuming the user queries can be satisfied by a manageable number of aggregate tables, I’d start by looking at materialised views

Comment: But how will it help, if I have to recalc this statistic every 30-60 sec?

Comment: Refresh the MVs every 30-60 sec? Any solution that involves doing something with your data (whether that's refreshing MVs, moving data to an OLAP system, etc) is going to take a measurable amount of time. If you can't wait for that time period then your only solution is to speed up queries on your current solution and your only options there are indexing and/or table partitioning